# QGIS query builder using QGIS variables

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

Is there any way to use QGIS variable values in QGIS query builder?

I would like to create a dynamic query which will load data from PostGIS based on a string value which equals the QGIS project filename. Like this:

```py
"project_name" =  base_file_name(  @project_filename )
```

Comment: Where did you want to input your query ? is it for filtering what is fetched from the database or for selecting in a layer or for creating a query layer or ...

Comment: The "Query builder" is one for filtering data fetched from the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a QGIS Python Macro.
QGIS Expression is not supported in the Query Builder.

Go in *Project properties* then *Macros*, the code is under the screenshot :

[image: Project properties macro]

Python code to use, you need to replace the `layer_id` variable :

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject
    
def openProject():
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    base_name = project.baseName()

    # Replace by the layer ID you need to filter, print(iface.activeLayer().id()) to have it
    layer_id = "observations_4a0f00d1_eba6_41b7_b196_1ee04ff3d50e"

    layer = project.mapLayer(layer_id)
    layer.setSubsetString("\"project_name\" = '{}'".format(base_name))
```

Comment: why two functions `closeProject()` and `saveProject()` are required?

Comment: They are not required. They are just by default when you open this tab in QGIS, with an empty project : `openProject`, `saveProject` and `closeProject`. I will remove.

Comment: it runs on error: Layer tablename: ERROR: column "somestring" does not exist
             LINE 1: ...T * FROM "public"."tablename" WHERE project_name = Somestring... I guess because the last row above inserting it without ' character.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed colunm and string formatting with `"` and `'`. You can still upvote if it works. I was trying with a integer sorry.

Comment: Brilliant, it works