# Use QGIS environment variable in QGIS query builder (filter)

Tags: qgis, macro

Is there a way to filter data in layer SQL query based on environment variable (`@my_variable`).

Similar to [QGIS query builder using QGIS variables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412662/qgis-query-builder-using-qgis-variables), but for user defined global variable.

Comment: In this question perhaps you will find a solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412662/qgis-query-builder-using-qgis-variables

Comment: In this question perhaps you will find a solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412662/qgis-query-builder-using-qgis-variables

Comment: In this question perhaps you will find a solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412662/qgis-query-builder-using-qgis-variables

Answer (score 1):

PyQGIS solution:

1. Define project variables in GUI (Menu Project\Properties\Variables) or with PyQGIS code:

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'myVariableName', value)
```

2. Then retrieve in PyQGIS (python console) the values with:

```
myVariable1 = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()).variable('myProjectVariable1')
myVariable2 = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()).variable('myProjectVariable2')
```

3. Finally set the filter with:

```
mylayer.setSubsetString("{} = {}".format(myProjectVariable1,myProjectVariable2))
```