# Use QGIS variables in PostGIS query

Tags: qgis, postgis, dbmanager

How can I build dynamic query to database?
In PostGIS database I have table with a column "column3" in which there are values project1, project2, project3, ... project23, project24.
I have QGIS project with title "project23".
It works well with arg as constant, just simle query in DBManager:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column3 = 'project23';
```

But DBManager not work with QGIS vars...
There are several virtual layers in the project where this is used. And every time you have to edit each layer manually. It works, but it's not comfortable!
What should I do to get rows where column "column3" has a value of dynamic ***@project_title*** instead of constant ***'project23'***?
I read it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412662/qgis-query-builder-using-qgis-variables?newreg=45a11d5e11bd45e096c9218c9cf0c4a4), but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: The linked answer updates the definition of an existing layer. Are you using an existing layer, or are you making queries "on the fly"? If it is the later, you could either save your query in a layer and use the proposed solution, or you could create a small script to copy (in memory) the project name and then just paste the value when you write your query

Comment: I'm using one project as a template.
The project contains multiple layers made as "load as new layer" from DBManager.
I want to use QGIS variable for example, a project_title (maybe another var) in a request. In the linked answer answer, it is not clear to me what I should insert into the request body.
So, if I changed the value of this variable, I would get a different result in all layers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `var()` in your DB Manager/Virtual Layer query to access global and project QGIS variables. (Not map-level variables such as `@zoom_level` or `@map_extent` - see [GitHub issue Allow more Expression scopes in virtual Layer SQL](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35867) for explanation).

So for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column3 = var('project_title');
```

Example of selecting variables:

[image]

Comment: This works great!
But:
- A layer is required that is loaded into the project, from which (as a virtual one) the next one is already selected.
- Unlike the macro solution, the result of this solution is not editable (this is not important to me now, but is important in general).

The question is whether there is a way to use a local variable directly in a database query so that QGIS does not read the entire table from the database, but filters objects at the query level.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't very clear what you were trying to achieve - you mentioned that your layers were loaded from DB Manager using 'Load as new layer' (which are always loaded as non-editable virtual layers) and that's the syntax used in your question as well. Now you want a layer that can be edited? So do you mean a filter in Query Builder then? Those are two different things. Please update your question to be clearer about exactly where you want to use the variable and include screenshots if that helps.

Comment: No no! I wrote that for solving my problem, the ability to edit is not important now. That's why I'm using the layer from the query, filtered by argument.
An important drawback of your solution for me is the need to first create a virtual layer from a database query, and then again create a virtual layer from the first layer.
This works, thanks, but makes the project structure too complex in my opinion. Obviously (if such a possibility exists), put a local variable in the request, then one action - one entity, this would be much more concise.

Comment: You could always combine the queries into one with some SQL syntax and only have one virtual layer... especially using a CTE or subquery.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you!
It turned out exactly what I was looking for. By using "Add Virtual layer" instead of DBManager you can add a database table and access it in a query.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution found!

By using "Create Virtual layer" instead of DBManager you can add a database table and access it in a query.
By clicking "Add", I have what I need!
[image: add virtual layer]